# How do I put a check mark into a bulma badge?

Tags: bulma

Bulma badge extension question

```
<button class="button is-small"
        data-badge="&#x2713;">
   Checked? 
</button>
```

This simply injects the code not the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

**It works fine!**

You have to include the Bulma CSS **and** the Bulma badge CSS (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wikiki/bulma-badge/master/dist/css/bulma-badge.min.css)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spinAround {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}

@keyframes spinAround {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}

[data-badge] {
  position: relative
}

[data-badge]::after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1rem .25rem;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #00d1b2;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-badge);
  z-index: 99
}

[data-badge][data-badge=""]::after {
  vertical-align: inherit
}

[data-badge].has-badge-white::after {
  background: #fff;
  color: #0a0a0a
}

[data-badge].has-badge-black::after {
  background: #0a0a0a;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-light::after {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #363636
}

[data-badge].has-badge-dark::after {
  background: #363636;
  color: #f5f5f5
}

[data-badge].has-badge-primary::after {
  background: #00d1b2;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-link::after {
  background: #3273dc;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-info::after {
  background: #209cee;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-success::after {
  background: #23d160;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-warning::after {
  background: #ffdd57;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-danger::after {
  background: #ff3860;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #00d1b2;
  color: #00d1b2
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-white::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-black::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #0a0a0a;
  color: #0a0a0a
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-light::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  color: #f5f5f5
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-dark::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #363636;
  color: #363636
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-primary::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #00d1b2;
  color: #00d1b2
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-link::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #3273dc;
  color: #3273dc
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-info::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #209cee;
  color: #209cee
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-success::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #23d160;
  color: #23d160
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-warning::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #ffdd57;
  color: #ffdd57
}

[data-badge].has-badge-outlined.has-badge-danger::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #ff3860;
  color: #ff3860
}

[data-badge].has-badge-rounded::after {
  border-radius: 290486px
}

[data-badge]::after {
  min-width: 1rem;
  min-height: 1rem;
  font-size: .75rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-left::after {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-bottom::after {
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-bottom-left::after {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-inline {
  margin-right: 1.5rem
}

[data-badge].has-badge-inline::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-inline.has-badge-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom {
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small::after {
  min-width: .75rem;
  min-height: .75rem;
  font-size: .5625rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-left::after {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-bottom::after {
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-bottom-left::after {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-inline {
  margin-right: 1.125rem
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-inline::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-inline.has-badge-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 1.125rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom {
  margin-right: 1.125rem;
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-small.has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 1.125rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium::after {
  min-width: 1.2rem;
  min-height: 1.2rem;
  font-size: .9rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-left::after {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-bottom::after {
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-bottom-left::after {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-inline {
  margin-right: 1.8rem
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-inline::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-inline.has-badge-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom {
  margin-right: 1.8rem;
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-medium.has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large::after {
  min-width: 1.4rem;
  min-height: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-left::after {
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-bottom::after {
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-bottom-left::after {
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%)
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-inline {
  margin-right: 2.1rem
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-inline::after {
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-inline.has-badge-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 2.1rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom {
  margin-right: 2.1rem;
  top: 50%;
  right: -20%
}

[data-badge].has-badge-large.has-badge-inline.has-badge-bottom-left {
  margin-right: inherit;
  margin-left: 2.1rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%
}

[data-badge].button:not(.is-clipped)::after {
  overflow: visible
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section">
  <button class="button is-small" data-badge="&#x2713;">
   Checked? 
</button>
</section>
```